# Intellij Insert File Template Header

Tags: intellij-idea

When you create a new java class in Intellij a file header is automatically inserted (based on "File Templates" options).  Is there a way to insert that same template into an existing java source file?  I was hoping there was a way to use my template definition on existing code without doing a cut/paste all over the place.  The template makes use of macro expansion and I hope to be able to keep that.  There is a similar function in eclipse called "Generate Element Comment" that would handle this case.  Does this exist within Intellij IDEA?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the best solution is to use a "Live Template" but you can´t reuse the File Template, so, you will need at last one copy/paste operation

Comment: This is what I ultimately did for this.  You lose the macro expansion, but I guess you can't always get what you want.

Answer (score 19):

Use Copyright header instead. Configure your Copyright profile as stated at [jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-and-updating-copyright-notice.html). Press Alt-Insert or Right mouse click -> select "Generate" -> "Copyright".

You can check what variables you can use in Copyright statement [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/copyright-profiles.html).

Answer (score 9):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header

Write This:

```
/**
 * @author : ${USER}
 * @mailto : buy@mail.com
 * @created : ${DATE}, ${DAY_NAME_FULL}
**/
```

To see an header like this:

```
/**
 * @author : BUY
 * @mailto : buy@mail.com
 * @created : 21/08/2020, Friday
 **/
public class Foo{}
```

Comment: Where is the value defined for USER?

Comment: @Bhuvan It is a predefined variable (System login name of the current user). When you use predefined variables in templates, they expand into corresponding values later in the editor.

Answer (score 6):

go to Settings > File and Code Templates then include tab and select header and define you

`/**
 * @author : Name
 * @since : ${DATE}, ${DAY_NAME_SHORT}
**/`

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your aim using the [Replacing all](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html) dialog.

Call the **Replacing all** dialog, in a top filed set a `package` word and in a bottom field set `\/\*\nYour file header\n\*\/\n\npackage` and press a **Replace All** button.

You can specify a set of files which should be upgraded by using a **In Project / Module / Directory / Scope** settings.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I do this by `Alfred Snippets`

Add following config in alfred snippet, and when I insert `!header`, it automaticlly insert wished template.

[image]