# Intellij not adding default javadoc comments with (/** + Enter)

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc, code-templates

I have a `file and Code Template` setup for `Class` files under my intellij `settings`
as

```
  #if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
    #parse("File Header.java")
    public class ${NAME} {
    }
```

I have some standard format setup in `Header.java` which I want to use everywhere.
So whenever I create a `new java class` I get the content of `Header.java` on top of class as comment.

But, If somehow I have an existing java class without the comment and I type `/** + Enter` I only get this

````
/**
 * 
 */```

I'm unable to find where to set these code template to have default class level javadoc comment to be created upon `/** + Enter` 

Using community Addition.
````

Comment: Are you sure you're having a `.java` file?

Comment: where ? in Templates include, yes..... where I'm trying to add comment- Yes

Comment: Mentioned template is used on file creation only.

Comment: @y.bedrov I know about mentioned template, just gave it as a reference, what I want in javadoc

Comment: It's not possible to generate header in existing file. Please try suggestions from related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778543/intellij-insert-file-template-header/17156047